# Can volcanos cause isostatic depression

Tags: volcanology, mantle, lithosphere

Isostatic depression is normally associated with glaciation, but can other geologic processes result in similar behavior of the lithosphere? Especially, can the weight of a volcano cause the surrounding lithosphere to sink.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they can. [Hawaiian Trough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_Trough) is a good example. The impact on thin oceanic crust is naturally larger/faster than on stiff continental crust.

Generally the lithosphere will always respond to load, even if it's sediments, ice or water. The process also works the other way, [exhumation by erosion](http://www.usu.edu/geo/pederson/Pederson%20et%20al.%202002%20GSA%20Today.pdf) ease the load and cause uplift.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. Lithospheric flexure due to volcanic edifice emplacement is well-documented. Not only do you get isostatic depression near the volcano, but further afield you actually can have uplift due to a "hinging" sort of effect. Lithospheric flexure drives the growth of underwater coral atolls through subsidence at a recently emplaced volcano (coral forms at a fixed depth beneath sea level), but later can lift the same coral above sea level due to far-field volcanic emplacement, turning the underwater atoll into an island. See the seminal work on this by [McNutt & Menard (1978)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/JB083iB03p01206/abstract).